# Mushroom Identification: Small conical light-brown mushroom

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found a small single mushroom growing on grass and I decided to try to identify it.

Characteristics:

- Region: Brazil southeast coast, state of São Paulo, predominantly Atlantic forest
- Gilled mushroom
- Substract of growth: Grass
- Dark coloured spores (I'd say yellow-brown. Picture Below)
- Gills either free or adnexed (My mistake this time, the cap was conical and small, so I couldn't have a clear view of the end of the gills. Should have cut it)
- Cap 1.6cm in diameter, conical shaped
- Height of about 6cm
- Very fragile, specially stipe. Dry texture
- Cap color: Like a faded orange or very light brown. Stipe color: Light cream

I tried to follow some identification keys (mostly [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_ubf43OTlAhWkGbkGHY1UBP8QFjACegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usask.ca%2Fbiology%2Fkaminskyj%2F342%2Flabmanual%2FAppendix%252007%2520Key%2520to%2520major%2520genera.doc&usg=AOvVaw1sPuHIDHjnxic6hzx22RM6), but [that one](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/gilled_dark.html) also seemed to go the same direction) and it pointed me towards the *Conocybe* genus, possibly *Conocybe apala* (item **45a** on the key from the link, you can follow back to the beginning going to the item on the parenthesis).

However, from what I read it's very hard to identify *Conocybe* mushrooms to the species level, because some are only differentiated by some microscopic features. They are also sometimes confused with mushrooms of *Bolbitius* or *Galerina* genus. Most mushrooms pictures I found from *Bolbitius* and *Galerina* give the impression they are a little more "fleshy" (not sure that's the word), and mine had this dry-fragile texture, which most pictures of *Conocybe apala* seem to align with.

Below are some pictures:

[image: Mushroom]

[image: Mushroom Gills]

[image: Spore print]

Is it likely a *Conocybe apala* or are there any other possible candidates?